# Picking Object3D loaded via OBJMTLLoader

Tags: three.js

When we load an Object3D with OBJMTLLoader, it is not possible to use raycaster to pick this object with mouse. Intersection array length is always 0. Any one knows the reason? Below is the code...

The loader routine

```
            var loader2 = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader2.load('/assets/unwrap/masa/dogtasmasa.obj', '/assets/unwrap/masa/dogtasmasa.mtl', function (object) {
            object.position.y = 1.5;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.z = 2;
            object.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
            object.rotateZ(-Math.PI / 2);
            object.scale.set(0.04, 0.04, 0.04);
            object.castShadow = true;
            scene.add(object);
        });
```

and the picking

```
        function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth - 5;
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 5;

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);


        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
                var obj = intersects[i].object;
                    controls.enabled = false;
                    tControls.attach();
            }
        }
        else {
            controls.enabled = true;
            tControls.detach();
        }
    }
```

The scene is the whole browser window. Any other mesh cerated via THREE types can be picked, but object3d not...

Thanks for all kinds of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the recursive flag like so:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

three.js r.66

Comment: i tried that, When i use resursive flag, intersection is made with lots of objects but i need to create a bounding box helper to show which object is selected. The child mesh of object3d has a bounding box around then. I need to create a bounding box helper around the group which is loaded. For example the object is my scene is a Sofa, but the sofa cannot be selected all..

Comment: Here is how that situation is handled in three.js: In the loader callback, you need to add to each child object a pointer to the root object, like so: `child.userData.rootObject = object;`.